# Writing function that takes an input (profession) and returns output (type of drink)

Tags: python

This code works for all valid inputs but if the input is invalid it should return "Beer". I am not sure if there is a way to include a variable in the dictionary that allows for all other unassigned inputs (like an "else" statement) in python, so tried an "else" statement at the end but this syntax is invalid as there is no "if" statement earlier. I've made a clumsy addition at the end with if input not in the list then return beer, however this does not work.

```
def get_drink_by_profession(param):
    p_to_d = param.title()
    return{
        "Jabroni":"Patron Tequila",
        "School Counselor":"Anything with Alcohol",
        "Programmer":"Hipster Craft Beer",
        "Bike Gang Member":"Moonshine" ,
        "Politician":"Your tax dollars",
        "Rapper":"Cristal",
        }[p_to_d]
    if param not in p_to_d:
        return "Beer"
```

Comment: Define "Finish off". I see code there, but not much else

Comment: Put the if statement in front of the return

Comment: Agree. When you call "return" the function is finished. Therefore the statement "if param not in p_to_d:" is never reached.

Comment: You really should define this dictionary globaly and refer to it inside the function instead of constructing the dict object every time the function is called.

Comment: Hi Nathan - would that one change then make an "else" statement work later on?
SiHa - edited it for clarity
Thanks ErebosM, Juanapa.arrivillaga for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the key is not found in the dictionary, a KeyError exception is thrown. You can catch this exception and return the default value.

```
def get_drink_by_profession(param):
    p_to_d = param.title()
    try:
      return{
          "Jabroni":"Patron Tequila",
          "School Counselor":"Anything with Alcohol",
          "Programmer":"Hipster Craft Beer",
          "Bike Gang Member":"Moonshine" ,
          "Politician":"Your tax dollars",
          "Rapper":"Cristal",
          }[p_to_d]
    except KeyError:
        return "Beer"
```

This way follows the [Python idiom: “it’s easier to ask for forgiveness than permission”](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/).

Answer (score 2):

You can do a [safe get](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) and give "Beer" as the default value,
if the key isn't present.

```py
def get_drink_by_profession(param):
    p_to_d = param.title()
    return{
        "Jabroni":"Patron Tequila",
        "School Counselor":"Anything with Alcohol",
        "Programmer":"Hipster Craft Beer",
        "Bike Gang Member":"Moonshine" ,
        "Politician":"Your tax dollars",
        "Rapper":"Cristal",
        }.get(p_to_d, "Beer")
```

Comment: Thank you this does the trick, I had tried it similar to what you suggested without the .get function and then had it returning "Beer" in addition to the other drinks that were showing up